# Update expiry date after recurring payment and Paypal

Tags: php, paypal

I'm looking to use `Paypal` to accept Credit Cards for a subscription service site. For example, someone would subscribe to the site and pay monthly. If they cancel, they would lose access to the site.

Customers would pay and get one month access and be billed monthly. Upon initially subscribing, an expiry date would be stored on the user account and if expired, the customer would lose access to the site.

How would I go about pushing the expiry date back one month every time a payment goes through successfully using `Paypal` and `PHP`?

Is this the best way to go about handling these kinds of subscriptions?

Thanks for any input!

`UPDATE`: 
Once the subscription is made a `PROFILEID` number is given by Paypal and I will store it in a database. Whenever a user logs in, I want to query `Paypal` to see if they have paid using the the `PROFILEID` tied to the account.

How would I go about querying `Paypal` for that?

Comment: Are you looking for their credit card to be paid automatically after month?

Comment: This would be using Paypal's recurring payments. Once they sign up a subscription gets made on in their Paypal account. I need to find out how to tell when the payment goes through to update the expiry.

Comment: Looks like you need to use PayPal's Instant Payment Notification (IPN) API https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/products/instant-payment-notification/

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways for doing this:-

1. Save the both dates ( start date and expiry date ) with the user in same table. And update them both when user make payment. Start date would be when user make payment and you can calculate end date and save them in table.
2. Secondly, you can store both dates in different table with user's key as foreign key and and new values to this table when ever user makes payment. And check for latest entry into table to check for user's subscriptions.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question. I know what to do one database side. How do I know when the payment actually goes through?

Comment: Users must be going to make payment after they hit button on your site and you must be coming back to you site after payment (sucessfull or not). When you come back check for success and update values in database.

Answer (score 0):

PayPal has a recurring payments product: https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/direct-payment/ht_dp-recurringPaymentProfile-curl-etc/